# How can you use Karma with different projects?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

We are using Karma to test our JavaScript.  We have different projects that work together.  So we have a projectA that gets deployed to pathA and a projectB that gets deployed to a pathB.  Also, we are using require.js.

How can we set this up?

Comment: Need more information, are these projects treated as a single application?  Should each project be using it's own karma configuration file?

Comment: They are all part of one application.  They reference each other.